# Access form group control inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor, mat-input, mat-error

In the template file I'm iterating over an array of elements and for each element a separate row is inserted.

Each element has the same set of controls, but whenever I enter a wrong value inside one of the input fields the same error message appears on all other input controls. I need it to validate only the current input field.

Hope I explained it clearly. Below is my template code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <td>
      <input matInput
             formControlName="elementNamePrefix"
             [required]="controls.elementNamePrefix.required"
             [placeholder]="controls.elementNamePrefix.displayName"
             [type]="controls.elementNamePrefix.type">
      <mat-error *ngIf="group.get('elementNamePrefix').hasError('maxlength')">
        Max length is XY characters!
      </mat-error>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you add more template code and the class?

Comment: do you mean parts is a formArray??

Comment: @AkhilNaidu it's an array defined inside the TS file. Guess formArray is how you call it. :)

Comment: Sorry but can you please post the structure or declaration of parts Array (ts code)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding `parts` is a `formArray`. Hence, you have to find the formGroup based on that index to display the error message in that particular control.

Try this condition in `<mat-error>` container.

```
<tr *ngFor="let part of parts; let i=index">
  <td>
      <input matInput
             formControlName="partNamePrefix"
             [required]="controls.partNamePrefix.required"
             [placeholder]="controls.partNamePrefix.displayName"
             [type]="controls.partNamePrefix.type">
    <mat-error *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('partNamePrefix').hasError('maxlength')">
        Max length is XY characters!
    </mat-error>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**TS :**

```
getFormGroup(index: number) {
  return (this.parts.controls.find((_controls, groupIndex) => (groupIndex === index)) as FormGroup)
}
```

Comment: @bigb055 I forget to mention `this.parts`. I updated my answer. I hope this.parts is a form array. Is it right ?

Comment: if parts is a formArray then try `return (parts.controls[index] as FormGroup)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related with the way you declare the input. You are using the same formControlName for all of them. Instead of it try to assign a dynamic one:

```
<tr *ngFor="let part of parts; index as i">
  <td>
    <input matInput
         formControlName="{{part.whatever}}"
         [required]="controls.partNamePrefix.required"
         [placeholder]="controls.partNamePrefix.displayName"
         [type]="controls.partNamePrefix.type">
    <mat-error *ngIf="group.get({{part.whatever}}).hasError('maxlength')">
      Max length is XY characters!
    </mat-error>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I get Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-error'.

Comment: That error is because mat-error component is not importing CommonModule in its module declaration. Try to put the *ngIf in a ng-container which surrounds mat-error instead of the mat-error component

Comment: Same result: "Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'"

Comment: Then add CommonModule to your module because it's your application where it is missing